# package gives me invalid literal for int

Tags: python, int, pycharm

I'm using the package openbte on PyCharm and I get this error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled>openbte -g -type=porous/square_lattice -shape=circle -porosity=0.25 -lx=10 -ly=10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\openbte-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('openbte==0.9.24', 'console_scripts', 'openbte')()
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\__main__.py", line 47, in main
    Geometry(**vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\geometry.py", line 83, in __init__
    data = self.compute_mesh_data()
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\geometry.py", line 91, in compute_mesh_data
    self.import_mesh()
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\geometry.py", line 470, in import_mesh
    n_nodes = int(f.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '28 28 1 0\n'
```

Essentially, I am not too sure on what the error means. After researching, I believe it means that some values cannot be converted to int. The f file in question is https://textuploader.com/d3uab. It seems to fail on the very first line. Anyone have any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: A line in that file is `28 28 1 0`, and you can't `int()` that value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using a newer version of gmsh (4.0). Once I downloaded gmsh 3.0 the format was correct for openbte.